# How to resynchronize setTimeout() with CoffeeScript? Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I developed a coffeescript for my AJAX notifications code. The code itself works without issue. The problem I am having, is I decided to use **setTimeout()** instead of **setInterval()** to avoid exhausting the threads and causing serious congestion. I rarely ever use coffeescript, and I need assistance in figuring out how to loop the setTimeout function, properly. How can invoke a recursive method call after setTimeout has successfully received data with the **getNewNotifications()** method?

**notifications.coffee**

```
class Notifications
  constructor: ->
    @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")

    if @notifications.length > 0
      @handleSuccess @notifications.data("notifications")
      $("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick

    setTimeout (=>
      @getNewNotifications()
    ), 5000

  getNewNotifications: ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "/new_notification_check.json"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "GET"
      success: @handleSuccess
    )

  handleClick: (e) =>
    $.ajax(
      url: "/notifications/mark_as_read"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "POST"
      success: ->
        $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(0)
    )

  handleSuccess: (data) =>
    items = $.map data, (notification) ->
      notification.template

    unread_count = 0
    $.each data, (i, notification) ->
      if notification.unread
         unread_count += 1

    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(unread_count)
    $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)

jQuery ->
  new Notifications
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `setTimeout` in `handleSuccess`?

Comment: You won’t me to add the same TimeOut method to the success block? To call it once on page load & once on the success of that call? What would your approach be in doing that?

Comment: It would, I believe, create a recursive call, as you want. You call it once, as you have it. Then call it again in `handleSuccess`. When the new `setTimeout` expires, it will call `handleSuccess` again. Which will create a new `setTimeout. When the new `setTimeout` expires, it will call `handleSuccess` again. Which will create a new `setTimeout. And so on.

Comment: Okay. Can you write that in solution form with the given code to demonstrate? I will do it myself, but it’s your solution at the end of the day

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to add a `setTimeout` to `handleSuccess` which will create the recursive call you are looking for:

**notifications.coffee**

```
class Notifications
  constructor: ->
    @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")

    if @notifications.length > 0
      @handleSuccess @notifications.data("notifications")
      $("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick

    setTimeout (=>
      @getNewNotifications()
    ), 5000

  getNewNotifications: ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "/new_notification_check.json"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "GET"
      success: @handleSuccess
    )

  handleClick: (e) =>
    $.ajax(
      url: "/notifications/mark_as_read"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "POST"
      success: ->
        $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(0)
    )

  handleSuccess: (data) =>
    items = $.map data, (notification) ->
      notification.template

    unread_count = 0
    $.each data, (i, notification) ->
      if notification.unread
         unread_count += 1

    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(unread_count)
    $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)

    setTimeout (=>
      @getNewNotifications()
    ), 5000        

jQuery ->
  new Notifications
```

Comment: Great, glad to help. Feel free to accept as well. It can be helpful for future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a little more cleanly using promises/async/await, although you may have to transpile the JS output to be browser compatible.

The abstract approach can be seen in the following example.

```
test = ->
  for i in [1,2,3]
    await new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
      setTimeout ->
        console.log(i)
        resolve()
      , 1000

# run asynchronously
setTimeout test

console.log("async loop is running")
```

Running this script prints each of the numbers in sequence, with a 1-second delay between each, then exits.

In terms of your code, it's not that different. `$.ajax` supports async/await ([guide](https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax/)), so you can change the `getNewNotifications` method to this

```
getNewNotifications: ->
  await $.ajax(
    url: "/new_notification_check.json"
    dataType: "JSON"
    method: "GET"
  )
```

and the call in the constructor to this:

```
setTimeout =>
  loop
    await new Promise (resolve, reject) =>
      setTimeout =>
        results = await @getNewNotifications()
        @handleSuccess(results)
        resolve()
      , 5000
```

This is nice because it removes the need for callbacks or recursion

Comment: Do I call the constructor only once or do I put the code in the HandleSuccess block again?

Comment: only once (no recursion)

Comment: I’m getting await is not defined for return await(new Promise(...)

Comment: ok you might have to transpile it to browser compatible js like i said. async/await is ES2017

Comment: Okay — I will try to now

Comment: By the way this is almost the exact same thing as [the example they give in their docs](https://coffeescript.org/#async-functions)